# Android button background color changes button size

Tags: java, android, button, styles

I am using a built-in theme for my Android app:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

I am happy with that theme, except I want to change the background color of a button. Here is how it looks by default:

[image: default]

Here's what happens when I add a background color to this button (`android:background="@color/play_bg"`):

[image]

Hey!? It basically changed all the button's size, padding and margins!

So I managed to get the expected result using the `backgroundTint` property (`android:backgroundTint="@color/play_bg"`):

[image]

Unfortunately, this is only supported since version 21 of the API, which is not acceptable for me.

So two questions:

- Why does changing the background messes with the rest of the button's properties?
- How do I get the expected result without `backgroundTint`?

And a bonus question: How can I get the expected result programmatically (I have dynamic buttons in my app, so this would be very useful)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change this color in your Java File. When your main class loads you can take an object of this button and then change color.

Here is how you define this button in Manifest file :

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="PLAY"
android:id="@+id/btn1"
... />
```

Now in your Java file when you are adding this XML layout you need to

```
Button b = (Button)findViewByID(R.id.btn1);
b.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

You may also use COLOR:
    COLOR.RED
The code below sometimes does not work for me :-
  b.setBackgroundColor(int color)

Comment: Nice. It works! Just for completeness, can you explain what the `PorterDuff.mode.MULTIPLY` does? Also, do you know why the "intuitive" solution with `android:background="@color/..."`  does not work?

Comment: We use PorterDuff mainly while designing Graphic Application. 

PorterDuff is described as a way of combining images as if they were "irregular shaped pieces of cardboard" overlayed on each other, as well as a scheme for blending the overlapping parts.

Here is  article I found that wil better explain you:
    http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html


java.lang.Object
   ↳ java.lang.Enum<android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode>
     ↳ android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode

Reference : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html

Comment: Regarding your question why your native approach did not work :

When you used background, the background was changed for the part where the text is. The background depends on the Text size that you are using.

For whole background change you may need setColorFiller(Color.RED)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I will be doing in this process

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:background="@color/play_as"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Or you can use this [link](http://angrytools.com/android/button/) which is more easy way of creating the buttons