# setColorFilter to change Button color has no effect

Tags: android, button

I have a few buttons in my app layout, and I want to change the color of those buttons dynamically. When I use

```
b.setBackgroundColor(0xFF386F00);
```

the color changes as expected, but the shape, size and padding of the button changes too, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31008279/3134778) related question.

I tried to use the solution suggested in that answer, but doing

```
b.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

has no effect on any of my buttons. I have no idea what could be the reason for this. The relevant code is this:

```
import android.widget.Button;
```

...

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hrlistitems, parent, false);

    Button b = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.HRlistB);
    b.setOnClickListener(onBButtonClicked);
    b.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    rowView.setTag(values.get(i).getId());

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.HRlisttext);
    textView.setText(values.get(i).toTitle());

    return rowView;

}
```

This is part of a custom adapter, which might complicate matters, but I also tried everything I tried on a "normal" button as well, without positive results. Also everything else in the adapter does exactly what I would expect.

This is the button part of the corresponding xml file

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/HRlistB"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/HRlist4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/HRlistB2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/HRlistB3"/>
```

This button is for some reason rendered as a small square (!), with some space around it, and the corners are rounded. I don't know why that is, but I was quite happy with the way it looks. If setting the background color, the size changes to actual 30dpx40dp, without any padding, and no rounded corners. I am trying to find a way to just change the color and leave the rest as it is.

Why is the ColorFilter not working?

How can I color my button without changing anything else about this button (like size etc.) as a side effect?

Comment: what is your button's background drawable?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean... Do you want me to post the xml file?

Comment: `the color changes as expected, but the shape, size and padding of the button changes too` so what is shape, size and padding of the button?

Comment: your button has no background, so how do you want to change its color filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set the filtered drawable as the button's background:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hrlistitems, parent, false);

    Button b = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.HRlistB);
    b.setOnClickListener(onBButtonClicked);
    Drawable buttonBackground = b.getBackground();
    if(buttonBackground != null) {
        buttonBackground.setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        b.setBackground(buttonBackground);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

But, if I can be honest, I don't understand the first part of your question:

> the color changes as expected, but the shape, size and padding of the button changes too

I think that your problem is that you are using an `AppCompat` theme so `Button` is changed to `AppCompatButton`.

In this case you have to use the `setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList tint)` method if you want to achieve that result.
Official documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))

**EDIT**

I see now that your button doesn't have a background, you can't use a `ColorFilter` to change it since the `Drawable` is null.

Comment: I think you might be right about the `AppCompat` theme, how do I check this? (I am new to android programming...)

Comment: @fifaltra Go to res -> values -> styles.xml anche check that your theme inherit from Theme.AppCompat

Comment: ah, ok, so: yes, I am using a appcompat theme. Now I'm trying to figure out how to use this colorstatelist :D

Comment: Hm, now I got this: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.Button.setBackgroundTintList, is this easily explained or should I ask a new question?