# Android set color filter in fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-button

So I am trying to set the `colorFilter` of an `ImageView` that is inside of a fragment activity. I can click on the button and it works as expected except when I try to set the colorFilter it crashes and says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setColorFilter(int, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)' on a null object reference
```

How can this be null if I am already clicking on it and it is working? How do I fix it? Here is my onCreateView:

```
myButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
myButton.setOnClickListener(this);

// testing
myButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

** ANSWER **
My solution as pointed out, I was using `app:srcCompat="@drawable` to set my imageView and not a background. So I just removed the `.getBackground`. Here is my solution:

```
myButton.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Gray), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setColorFilter to change Button color has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442775/setcolorfilter-to-change-button-color-has-no-effect)

Comment: @AliAhmed I looked at that as well, that isn't for fragment activity and that is about the color not showing up, mine is crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your getBackground is giving null.
You have a imageview. May be you set its "src" not "background" in xml. 
If you want to continue with same, then set background in xml.

Thanks

Comment: You were correct, I was using `src` and not background, I just had to remove the .getBackground and use setColorFilter. Thanks